# Call Asynchronous webservice in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

I need to invoke some functions in a C# webservice after returning the result to the user, so I intend to use a OneWay method.

I created 2 webservices on the same project as following:
1st: the caller service:

```
public class Caller : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {

    var bg = new Background();
    bg.HelloWorldBG();
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

2nd the service to be invoked in the background:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public class Background : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void HelloWorldBG()
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    var file = @"D:\testHello.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");
}
```

}

but when I call HelloWorld() it doesn't return before completing the execution of HelloWorldBG()

Comment: Of course because you're just calling a method (HelloWorld) of a class like any other (from compiler perspective it doesn't matter if its base class is a web service). Use threadpool to call it asynchronously (or Tasks if .NET 4+)

Comment: For all the details to perform Asynchronous webservices see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121345/Asynchronous-Communication-in-a-WCF-Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a separate thread picked out from thread pool by starting a new task with your method:

```
var bg = new Background();
Task.Factory.StartNew(bg.HelloWorldBG);
return "Hello World";
```